# Unable to connect remotely from other devices + Vorlon

Tags: remote-debugging, vorlon

Vorlon dashboard is not showing all connected devices. 
I have desktop and installed a Vorlon, I am using localhost of this desktop from laptop or ipad its displays webpage but it is not showing devices in vorlon, but it show if i open from the same desktop.

Answer (score 2):

I was my bad. I am using localhost:1337 to load vorlon.js. We have to use ip address instead of localhost from other machine

Comment: I have the same problem, I think, and I'm wondering if you could elaborate on what the solution was? Thanks in advance!

Comment: instead of using localhost:1337 we have to use 10.20.155.44:1337 (10.20.155.44 is system IP)

Answer (score 0):

There can be a few different problems at play here.

First you need to find the IP address of the computer that is hosting your application/site i.e. 192.168.10.4.

1. start vorlon

   c:/> vorlon -v
2. start webserver,  ensure you use the same IP address found above

   c:/>python web2py.py --i 192.168.10.4 -p 8000
3. add script tag for vorlon

Both python and nodejs have to be allowed through the firewall, so next add rules for both the python executable you are using (which could be a virtualenv) and nodejs.

Finally you need to ensure that there are no other firewall rules that match the ports or applications you use, this is critical as I had a conflicting firewall rule for nodejs that was blocking the connection to nodejs and hence the script /vorlon.js cannot be found.

Hope this helps.