# Debugging iPad Safari with Vorlon

Tags: javascript, debugging, ipad, vorlon

I am trying to debug my javascript application while running on iPad Safari using Vorlon.

In the application HTML-code I have implemented the script link:

```
<script src="http://192.168.1.134:1337/vorlon.js"></script>
```

The IP is the IP of the Vorlon server, which is on my laptop. Running the app on the laptop - the same as the server is on - results in a new client connection in the Vorlon console. But on the iPad the app does not connect to the Vorlon server.

On my Galaxy Tablet the result is the same, no connection. No matter what browser. Tried Chrome and Firefox on the tablet.

I have checked the firewall on the laptop and made sure the 1337 port is allowed.

The laptop runs Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: are the iPad and the laptop on the same network? (check their IP addresses). some router manufacturers keep wifi and wired networks on separate ranges on purpose, and some even hide the wired network from the wireless)

Comment: It looks there is something going wrong there. Both machines are connected to WiFi and are not able to ping oneanother. Machines connected to LAN all can be pinged... I'll test it on my LAN connected PC, see if that one will receive the sessions.

Comment: try putting the laptop on the same wifi network, disconnect wired connection, try again.

Comment: They are both on the same WiFi connection already.

Comment: then your problem is most likely in the config of the firewall of your pc or router

Comment: refer to the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546118/unable-to-connect-remotely-from-other-devices-vorlon/54102329#54102329

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timothy was right. But to be a bit more exact: the WLAN router I got from my internet provider has a WLAN interface and four LAN interfaces. It turns out that nodes on the WLAN can not see each other, but they can see the machines connected to my LAN interfaces, like my NAS, my PC and the printer.

So the iPad - connected to the WLAN - is able to connect to the Vorlon-server on my PC and I now can start debugging.